# Newton type method for finite fields?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, finite-fields, computational-number-theory

I have a polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ that is easy to compute for any $x$ but has an absurdly large degree $d > 2^{256}$. I know for a fact that it has a zero and I would like to find it.

I was wondering, consider a modified newtons method where instead of
$$ x \to x - f(x)/f'(x)$$
we take the forward difference map
$$x \to x - f(x)/\Delta f(x)$$
and study this modulo $q$. Has this been studied?
Under what conditions will I get my zero?

In general I'm looking for root finding methods in a finite field that don't take gcds (I can't because of the degree) and only rely on point evaluations.

Comment: Is $q$ a prime or a prime power?

Comment: In any case, without a topology to rely on, there is little change that Newton's method will work. Chances are that your forward difference map will behave more or less like a random map except that it will have a fixed point, corresponding to your root.

Comment: Note that when the degree is large enough, every map is a polynomial map (by interpolation).

Comment: If a field has order $q$, any function from the field to itself can be implemented by a polynomial of degree less than $q$. So in general you can't use the values at some points to say anything about the values at other points, unless of the order of the field is much greater than the degree of the polynomial. Of course that might not be true if your polynomial has a special form.